# using admob alongside with static banners

Tags: android, admob

I have an android app. I have a banner located in bottom of the main page. This banner doesn't belong to any ad network but it's an advertisement of a web site. Can I use admob in some pages, and use that in other pages is it legal according to admob's rules?

Comment: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6275345?hl=en clearly states we cannot have add near interactive elements, assuming the banner when clicked will open the site would be disallowed, just keep the buttons, banners, links away from admob ads.

Comment: you can use https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3210452?hl=en, inhouse ads instead

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use admob in some pages, and use that in other pages is it legal according to admob's rules?

Yes, as long as you have one ad per screen you are alright. Source of ad does not matter. It could be from a network or locally stored

Answer (score 0):

Right, u can use one ad per screen, but if you have ads at the app launch - you can get some problems with AdMob. I'd say that banners as a prior format are not that cool, cause they are disturbing for many users, especially gamers. At the same time if you have a utility app, this might work. I'd suggest using interstitials or video if it's a game. Also try Ad mediation like Appodeal, MobFox or HeyZap this can help cover other networks alongside with Admob.